# ¿Cómo agrego correctamente la imagen al JoptionPane?

Tags: java, joptionpane, imageicon

mis carpetas serian

src ___ algoritmodefloyd ---- algoritmodefloyd.java

:

:

:---img ---- logo1.png

y el siguiente código no me funciona no salta error ni nada, pero no me lee la ruta y no aparece la imagen.

`ImageIcon logo = new ImageIcon("./img/logo1.png");`

`JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ruta.algoritmoFloyd(matrizA,nodos),`
`"Algoritmo de Floyd Warshall",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,logo);`

Cual seria a solución porfa

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

El problema que yo veo es como creas el objeto icono, necesitas hacer una llamada a los métodos getClass() y getResources().
Prueba con esto cuando crees el objeto icono:

```
Icon icono = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("ruta de la imagen"));
```

Espero que esto solucione tu problema.